# PHP contact form to mail.

Tags: php, forms, contacts

The code below:

```
'$mailto = $_POST['rec1'] ; //destination email'
```

is from the php file that processes the contents of form and send to the email address 'rec1'. rec1 is the name of the textfield in the form where the user is suppose to enter a valid email address and the message will sent to the email addresses entered. Now, i have multiple textfields (as shown below)

```
'<input name="rec1" maxlength="60" size="17" />'
'<input name="rec2" maxlength="60" size="17" />'
'<input name="rec3" maxlength="60" size="17" />'
```

I've tried using:   '$mailto = $_POST['rec1, rec2, rec3']'

to send the messages to the multiple addresses entered but it's not working. How can i send the messages to the multiple email addresses entered in the textfield?

Comment: Without validating the `$mailto` variable against a white-list of addresses you've just created a vehicle for spammers.

Comment: Did that before. it's validated. Thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

The dot operator provides string concatenation:

```
$_POST['rec1']. ', ' . $_POST['rec2'] . ', ' . $_POST['rec3']
```

Comment: It won't work if you use quotes wrong. In your original example: '$mailto = $_POST['rec1, rec2, rec3']' you have to remove the first and last quote, i.e. before $mailto and after ].

Answer (score 1):

```
$mailto = $_POST['rec1'] . "," . $_POST['rec2'] . "," . $_POST['rec3'];
```

Comment: Why don't you post your entire form script and mail script? There's another error in there somewhere causing this not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Access each POST var separately and separate each address with a comma.

```
$mailto  = $_POST['rec1'] . ', '; 
$mailto .= $_POST['rec2'];
```

Comment: That means that there is something wrong with your script because this is correct (check the corresponding php manual for mail function). Have you checked the content of $_POST? BTW: Two others wrote exactly the same answer as me. So what do you think? That we three are wrong or that there is a problem with your script?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$mailto = join(', ',array_values(array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip(array('rec1','rec2','rec3')))));
```

:)

actually I would go this route:

```
<input name='rec[]' maxlength='60' size='17' />
<input name='rec[]' maxlength='60' size='17' />
<input name='rec[]' maxlength='60' size='17' />

...

$mailto = join(', ', $_POST['rec']);
```